# how to change date format from 201904 to Apr-19 in excel

Tags: excel

In Excel, the date is in format 201904 I want to convert it to Apr-19.
I have used a custom format mmm-yy but it is changing it to Apr-52 instead of Apr-19

Comment: Definitely Apr-52 and not Oct-52?  I ask as Oct-52 is 201904 days after Excel's calendar starts on 1st Jan 1900... or is it 31 Dec 1899 (00/01/1900)... always confuses me.

Comment: didi you find the solution

Comment: Did @user11222393 post the solution?  If so can you tick it as correct - gives them some recognition and lets others know the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel recognizes this `201904` as a number.

And dates in Excel are numbers counting from `1900 01 01` as "Day 1".

If you convert your number (day count) to date, for example `"yyyy mm dd"`, it gives result `2452 10 15` while `"mmm-yy"` drops first t2 numbers from years and returns your seen year `52`

In this case you need to construct a recognizable date, but keep in mind that you will need to add day to date as only full date (year, month, day) can be recognized as a date in Excel.

Use `LEFT` to extract year and `RIGHT` to extract month. Add any day (1 in example) and you have date in Excel. Format it as "mmm-yy" to get your desired result:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),RIGHT(A1,2),1)
```

[image]